# the meaning and usuage of the variance of a discrete random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

We know that the variance in continuous normal disturbed random variable, enable us to calculate confidence intervals. But I just have to wonder what is the point in calculating variance of a discrete random variable. consider [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1856924/what-is-the-variance-of-the-following-random-variable) question for example. in that question, both mean and variance of the variable is $1$ and the lower bound of the variable is $0$ which means it can be, at max, only $1$  standard deviation under the mean.

can we calculate any confidence interval in that question using variance ? can we draw any conclusion about the probability of having $X=3$ knowing the variance and the probability of $X=2$ for example ?

Comment: "contentious" seems misplaced; what do you mean by that?

Comment: @joriki, thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: To take simple examples, the variances of Poisson or Binomial random variables are meaningful, and useful in senses other than confidence intervals.  Meanwhile if you do not know the actual distribution, but do know the mean and variance, you could use Chebyshev's inequality for some sort of conservative confidence interval, but for example it might reach about $4.47$ standard deviations from the mean rather than $1.96$ standard deviations

Comment: thank @Henry, I was indeed more relating to distribution which is not readily seen, as the one in the example.  I will inquire more into that Chebyshev's inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can use Chebyshev's inequality, which for $t \gt 0$ two-sided is $$P[|X-E(X)|\ge t] \le \frac{Var(X)}{t^2}$$
and one-sided  is
$$P[X-E(X)\ge t] \le \frac{Var(X)}{Var(X)+t^2}$$
but be aware that it tends to be very conservative: I once constructed a table and chart at http://www.se16.info/hgb/cheb.htm#Disc showing that the two-side interval for no more than $5\%$ probability outside the interval was about $4.47$ standard deviations from the mean, rather than about $1.96$ standard deviations from the mean for a normal distribution.  Compare the red and green lines of

[image]